# Some digitally signed pdfs shown as verified in the pdf viewers while others are not

Tags: digital-signature, pdf

I have two pdf documents:

1 - My class 10 marksheet issued by the [CISCE](http://cisce.org) that I downloaded through [digilocker](http://digilocker.gov.in/).

2 - My Domicile certificate issued and downloaded from the [aaplesarkar](https://aaplesarkar.mahaonline.gov.in/en) website.

Both documents are digitally signed, and show a green tick symbol when opened in Adobe Acrobat reader. But, when I the documents in a pdf viewer like Google Chrome on my PC or Pdf Viewer on my Android Phone, my marksheet shows a yellow question mark with the text "Signature Not Verified"

[image: Signature Not Verified]

while my domicile certificate shows a green tick with the text "Signature vaid".
[image: Signature Valid]

Why is this so? Is there anything I can do so that my marksheet also shows a green tick when opened in a pdf viewer?

Note that the digital signature on the Domicile certificate is in fact an actual digital signature and not just an image. I can right click the signature in Adobe Reader and click "Verify".

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's PDF viewer (and probably the viewer on your phone too) do **not** verify digital signatures at this time.

Here's a [page](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/9035087?hl=en) *from Google Support* that says:

> To validate a digital signature, you must use Adobe PDF software, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader. PDF viewers such as Apple's Preview or Chrome’s PDF Viewer cannot be used.

The usual way to validate a digital signature is to use the **free** version of Adobe's PDF software. While other PDF software can also be used, if the signature **doesn't** verify with Adobe's sw, then some people will suspect the signature no matter what.

Also note that Adobe's PDF software has many options including whether the software will verify an [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol). Or look up the signer's cert in the appropriate CRL.

If the setting is off (the default that I've seen), then the software can "successfully verify" a signature when the signature is not, in fact, valid. Whether that's good or bad depends on your goals... :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that Chrome’s PDF Viewer does not verify digital signatures. My question is that why does one document show a tick mark with the text "Signature vaid" while another document IN THE SAME VIEWER (Chrome PDF Viewer) shows a yellow question mark with the text "Signature Not Verified"? @Larry